# Convert Date to time stamp in java

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I am trying to convert the date to timestamp

`Thu Jul 04 13:32:51 IST 2013` to timestamp value

```
java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new
                   Timestamp(user.getCreatedTime().getTime());
           System.out.println("Today is " +timeStampDate);
```

but it gives the result as `2013-07-04 13:32:51.0` I need only the long value like 1372924971000.

Comment: Long value is the result of `user.getCreatedTime().getTime()`. You can just print it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime%28%29) on your `Timestamp` object:

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Timestamp object.

In fact you don't have to create a `Timestamp` first. `user.getCreatedTime().getTime()` already gives you the long value which you want.

Comment: Just to clarify, Date#getTime() returns this Date as a millisecond value. The value is the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970, midnight GMT.

Answer (score 0):

Call [this function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime%28%29) on your timestamp object:

```
timeStampDate.getTime()
```

As the doc states:

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by
>       this Timestamp object.

Fun fact:
The origin date used to measure elapsed time is referred to as the epoch.  Here for instance, January 1, 1970 is the epoch.

You could actually just call:

```
user.getCreatedTime().getTime()
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are looking for epoch time simple use

```
long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
```

Comment: No. He's looking for the elapsed time since the epoch for when the user was created.